# Posting data as multipart/form-data the MVVC/AngularJS way

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, go

I am developing a webapp using AngularJS for the frontend (still very new to JS) and Go for the backend and I am stumped trying to POST `multipart/form-data` encoded data instead of URL encoded.  I have tried to google it, but I cannot seem to find an example that doesn't assume that I'm only trying to upload a file. I am simply trying to POST a simple form with some text fields and no files.

I can get it work by bypassing Angular with a simple html form using `method="POST"`, but it is surprisingly difficult to do in javascript.

On the server side, I am decoding the POST request with `http.Request.FormValue("key")`.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Cheers!

Comment: If you can get work by submit a normal form then the problem must be in client side.

Comment: The problem is definitely in the client. I am having trouble encoding the multipart/form-data that i am sending to my Go backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the posibility to invoke the `submit()` of the form element (using jQuery here):

```
$('#yourForm').submit();
```

This will (of course) require that the endpoint targeted by the form handle the "full browser rollby" - and redirect properly.

It might be a better solution (since you control both frontend and backend) to have the Angular application submit JSON (as it defaults) and just handle that on the backend.

Comment: Will probably go with json. I think i may be over-complicating things a bit. That is a better solution than designing the backend to accommodate a shortcomming in the client.